# Search Only One Field Using Pipe In Angular

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-forms, angular-pipe

I have this project lists in my JSON and I only want to search the project name and disregard the other fields. My problem now is that it also searches other fields. How can i do searching using the project name only in my pipe  without other fields affecting it. Here's what I've done below.

> JSON

```
{
  "token": "ejsk0e",
  "projects": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Store",
      "description": "Small",
      "organization_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2017-10-29 10:31:50",
      "updated_at": "2017-11-14 06:27:03",
      "material_projects": [
        {
          "id": 18,
          "material_id": 40,
          "project_id": 5,
          "quantity": 10,
          "unit": "pcs",
          "created_at": "2017-11-02 09:57:14",
          "updated_at": "2017-11-02 09:57:14",
          "material": {
            "id": 40,
            "sku": "ACWNAIL",
            "name": "Banana",
            "created_at": "2017-10-26 03:19:54",
            "updated_at": "2017-10-26 03:23:21"
          },
          "categories": [
            {
              "id": 8,
              "name": "Fruits",
              "created_at": "2017-10-26 07:36:48",
              "updated_at": "2017-11-10 02:06:07",
              "pivot": {
                "material_proj_id": 18,
                "category_id": 8
              }
            }
          ],
          "material_name": "Banana",
          "material_sku": "ACWNAIL",
          "category_name": "Fruits"
        }
  ]
}
```

> TS

```
 getAllProjects() {
    this.subscription = this.projectsService.getAll()
      .subscribe(
        (data:any) => {
          this.projects = data.projects;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }
```

> HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <input placeholder="Search..."" type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchProj">
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let project of projects | search : searchProj">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h2 class="proj-name">{{ project.name }}</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> PIPE.ts

```
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

      transform(items: any, term: any): any {
        if (term === undefined) return items;

        return items.filter(function(item) {
          for(let property in item){
            if (item[property] === null){
              continue;
            }
            if(item[property].toString().toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())){
              return true;
            }
          }
          return false;
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: you should not use pipes for filtering operations, filtering is a cpu intensive opertion, and pipe transforms trigger on every single change detection cycle whether needed or not, this practice will result in poor application performance, the better method is to use observables to trigger filtering only when needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to your problem is to just feed the property as variable into your pipe:

```
transform(items: any, term: any, prop: string): any {
    if (!term || !prop) return items;

    return items.filter((item) => 
        item[prop].toString().toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()));
  }


<div class="row" *ngFor="let project of projects | search : searchProj : 'name'">
```

HOWEVER...

You should never do things like sorting and filtering in a pipe transform.  Pipe transforms trigger on every single change detection cycle, which is extremely frequent, and this leads to sorting and filtering being reapplied on every change detection cycle whether they are needed or not, this results in extremely poor app performance.  In fact, angularJS included a filter pipe, but it was removed due to wide spread abuse that led to poor application performance.  The better method is to build in the logic of when you need to trigger sorting or filtering yourself instead of relying on change detection to do it for you.

this is easier with reactive forms instead of ngModel, so my sample will use that.

TS:

```
this.projects$ = this.projectsService.getAll();
this.searchProj = new FormControl('');
this.search$ = this.searchProj.valueChanges.startWith('').debounce(300).distinctUntilChanged();
this.filteredProjects$= Observable.combineLatest(this.projects$, this.search$)
                                  .map(([projects, searchTerm]) => (searchTerm) ? projects.filter(p => p.name.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) : projects);
```

then your html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <input placeholder="Search..."" type="text" [formControl]="searchProj">
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let project of filteredProjects$ | async">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h2 class="proj-name">{{ project.name }}</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

to walk you through this code, first you store your service method for retrieving the projects in an observable, then you make a form control for your search term, then you store it's value changes method in an observable, telling it to first start with an empty value and then debounce it and only get distnct values (this is a minor optimization so that if a user quickly types you only actually search every couple of characters and don't research if they quickly enter and remove a character).  Then you combine those two in a new observable, and map them together into your filter function, so that the projects get filtered each time either item changes.

as for your original problem... this is now a non factor since you're not using something as generic as a pipe, you can just explicitly filter on the name property, or you could just take the transform function above and use it in your map operator to not repeat the filtering logic if you use it frequently.

Comment: Thanks a lot bryan. I'll try using your suggestion. Thanks for the new info.